# Como puedo editar contenido de un TD desde jquery sin hacer referencia de el con un id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un botón dentro de un `TD`, quiero que al presionar ese botón el contenido del `TD` cambie por medio de `jquery`, pero no quiero ponerle un `id` al `td` para hacer referencia de el porque son muchos `td` que tengo que poner la misma opción. Solo quiero cambiar el `td` donde se encuentra el botón.

```
<tr>
    <td>Primer Nombre</td>
    <td> <input type="text" value="" disabled> </td>
    <td> <button type="button">Editar</button></td> <!-- el td que quiero cambiar el contenido -->
</tr>
```

Este es el código `jquery` que intenté usar pero no me funcionó

```
$(this).parent("td").html("Contenido nuevo");
```

Comment: puedes agegar el contenido de tu código, sería más fácil para todos poder ayudarte, también lee [ask] para que formules preguntas que sean bien aceptadas por el grupo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario que agregues el `td` por que el `parent()` te da el padre inmediato del elemento en cuestión te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){        
         $(this).parent().html("Contenido nuevo");
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Primer Nombre</td>
       <td> <input type="text" value="" disabled> </td>
       <td> <button type="button">Editar</button></td> <!-- el td que quiero cambiar el contenido -->
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, gracias.